# How to use json data as highcharts Pie Chart?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, charts, highcharts

I've created an ajax request that returns data like this

```
Object
negative:3
neutral:3
positive:94
```

This is directly from `console.log();`

Im trying to create a pie chart using this data but when I try it doesn't draw the chart and nothing shows up except for the credits and no errors in the console either. But if I manually input data like this:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            data: [

                { name: 'Positive', y: 94 },
                { name: 'Negative', y: 3 },
                { name: 'Neutral', y: 3 },
            ]
        }]
```

it works no problem.

My code is:

```
function pieChart(data) {
    // Make monochrome colors and set them as default for all pies
    Highcharts.getOptions().plotOptions.pie.colors = (function () {
        var colors = [],
            base = Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
            // Start out with a darkened base color (negative brighten), and end
            // up with a much brighter color
            colors.push(Highcharts.Color(base).brighten((i - 3) / 7).get());
        }
        return colors;
    }());

    // Build the chart
    Highcharts.chart('pieChart', {
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Browser market shares at a specific website, 2014'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
                    style: {
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Brands',
            data: data
        }]
    }); 
};
```

Comment: How looks exactly your json ? You need to return json from server , or create it on client-side.

Comment: Thanks, the response is being returned from the server. `console.log()` the data returned outputs `Object {positive: 94, negative: 3, neutral: 3}`

Comment: Lets continue here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130280/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-5471291-javascript-with-jquery-click-and-doubl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you've received from server using `ajax` request is an object.

All you need is to create a `json` array from the response you've received.

```
var object={'positive':94,'neutral':2,'negative':2};
var data=[];
for(i in object){
    data.push({"name":i,"y":object[i]});
}
```

And set it to `highchart` series.

```
series: [{
        name: 'Brands',
        data: data
}]
```